# asp.net http handlers and http modules does it work without using IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can i only use HTTP handlers or HTTP modules if i use my ASP.NET website with IIS or NOT?

And besides that, what is actually the main difference between an http handler and a http module??

Comment: Where do you intend to use your asp.net website?

Comment: When you say if I use my asp.net website with IIS or not? How do you intend to use your website with out IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article should explain the difference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx

As to using them in IIS or not - if you are running the built in Visual Studio Webserver you can run Http Handlers. I believe modules require a web server to do the mapping, but I stand to be corrected.